# Can I have a Laravel 4.2 blade include with it's own controller?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have a sidebar include file that is present on every page of the website I am working on.

**layout.blade:**

```
<div class="after-login buying-process-wrapper">
  <!--page content-->
  {{ $content }}
  <!-- end of page content-->

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  @include('layout.sidebar')
  <!-- End of Sidebar -->
</div>
```

My controller sets $layout and renders the above blade file, but `layout.sidebar` is an include file which requires PHP to populate it's content.

Can I set a controller/route for this sidebar alone (and how would I do it?), or am I forced to have to duplicate the same calls to the function that handles the sidebar content in every controller?

I'm trying to find a better solution than having to go in to every controller and calling ->sidebar() every time each page is loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you still using Laravel 4.2? It't 5.7 now and I strongly recommend you to upgrade to the latest version.

Answer to your question:

No, you don't need to call functions that handle your sidebar contents in every controller. You can share you common data across all or some of your views by using `View Composer`. 
From [`Laravel` 4.2 Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#view-composers):

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want bound to a given view each time that view is rendered throughout your application, a view composer can organize that code into a single location. Therefore, view composers may function like "view models" or "presenters".

If you are using newer versions of `Laravel`， remember to switch to the right documentation from the right upper corner.

Also, when using `Blade` `@include` directive, you can optionally pass variables into the "included" components:

```
@include('layout.sidebar', ['my_var' => 'value goes here'])
```

And you can use `{{ $my_var }}` in your component just like you normally would in your blade templates.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your answer! In answer to your question about Laravel versions, If you've worked in the software industry for any length of time, then you should know that suggesting upgrading to a newer version is not a valid answer! Why am I on Laravel 4.2? Because that's what the product is built on. Not 5.7, and it is in no way worth the companies time to upgrade to 5.7 at this point. Imagine a large project with hundreds of files built on 4.2... :)

Comment: @simonw16 Yes I totally understand your situation. There is always struggle on whether to upgrade or not. Is it worth the effort? Is it absolutely necessary? The way I see it is that version 4.2 is really really outdated. If you've got a chance, you should absolutely try new versions, even if you are just using it for a toy project, you get to know some of the features that older versions don't possess ;)

Comment: Yup, I'd love to upgrade it honestly, but the time just doesn't exist to do so :(. Never mind though. One day when all the tasks are complete, and we have time to do some codebase clean up, it'll be high priority!

Comment: @simonw16 Great! Each company has its own plans and upgrading existing projects can be very painful and time consuming. Nevertheless, `Laravel` is an amazing framework and I hope you'll enjoy using it!